# Eat of its fruit

Tags: blessing, trees

How can we say in *Al Hamichyah* ונאכל מפריה (eat of its fruit) after ובנה ירשלים (and you will rebuild Jerusalem) You are not allowed to grow trees in  ירשלים?

Comment: Where does it say that in Bentching? I think you mean in Al Hamichya...

Comment: I think You should write Al Hamichyah instead of Meayn Shalosh its a more familiar term.

Comment: Why aren't you allowed to grow trees in Yerushalayim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **Griz** answers with another question.

Where is the  Halacha that you have to eat בקדושה ובטהרה (in purity)?

The question is the answer the fruit referred to in ונאכל מפריה must be talking about  מעשר שני *Masser Sheni* which Halachicly must be eaten in Yerushalayim (NOT GROWN) so  ונאכל מפריה is talking about מעשר שני and the Halacha is it must be eaten בקדושה ובטהרה.

חידושי מרן הגריז החדשות אות-סב

Comment: Awesome! Where is this in the Gri"z? Al HaTorah, in his Hiddushim etc.?

Comment: The Brisker Rov is quoted in the Brisker Hagadah page 232 in the name of "Kisvei Hatalmidim".

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps indeed because of these two questions (the one in the original post and in YS' answer), Nusach Ari omits this phrase; the wording there is ובנה ירושלים... והעלנו לתוכה, ושמחנו בה, ונברכך בקדושה ובטהרה.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the Baal HaTanya formulated Nusah Ari with more than just questions as proof for his text. At least that is what it seems from Sefer Shaar Hakollel.

Comment: Of course. The fact is that I don't know why his version is different (there's nothing about it, that I've found, in Shaar Hakollel or in Dayan Raskin's notes on the Siddur). But in fact, I find that at least the Shaloh's siddur also omits the entire phrase, though it's worded a bit differently (facsimile at http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22373&st=&pgnum=534) - so it may be that he, or indeed someone going back to the Arizal, objected to the ונאכל מפריה wording for whatever reason.

Comment: Alex, yiyasher kohacha for the Shelah source!

Answer (score 2):

The [Brisker Rov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitzchak_Zev_Soloveitchik) says this is a reference to Maaser Sheni; while usually grown outside of Jerusalem, it's eaten in Jerusalem.

(What's this law about no trees anywhere in Jerusalem?  I thought it was just the Temple Mount.)

This also explains the next phrase: "and we shall consume of them in holiness and purity."  While purity preceeds holiness in our spiritual endeavors (look at the chapter ordering in Mesilas Yesharim), here it's the fruit that's holy, and we have to eat it while pure.  (Kedusha is on the cheftza; tahara is on the gavra.)

---

I think the simplest answer is to rethink the structure of the bracha:

- For the fruit,
- And for the land,

  - A desirable, goodly, wide-open land, that you gave our forefathers so they could enjoy its bounty.
- Have mercy on Jerusalem, the Temple, and the Altar; rebuild Jerusalem speedily
- Bring us back to *it*, let us rejoice in its being built, let us enjoy its fruit and bless you

What's *it*?  Jerusalem?  Or the entire land?  Depends how you read it.  We talk about gathering the exiles back to *the land*, but not necessarily that everyone will move only to Jerusalem for year-round residence.  On the other hand, we usually talk about rebuilding Jerusalem, not the whole land.  But if you read *it* as the whole land, the above question is moot.

Comment: The "no trees anywhere in Jerusalem" rule is in Bava Kamma 82b, one of ten halachos that apply to the city as a whole. The Gemara there gives the reason משום סירחא (because of the bad smell) - as Rashi says, either of discarded weeds or of fertilizer.

Comment: Awesome! Where is this in the Gri"z? Al HaTorah, in his Hiddushim etc.?

Comment: Your second answer seems more possible when one adds that U'vnei Yerushalayim was added in only later by Raban Yohanan Ben Zakkai after Hurban Bayis Sheini. However the kedusha vtahara problem is not resolved.

Comment: True that the wording ובנה ירושלים was obviously added only after the Churban, but before that the blessing in Birkas Hamazon (and hence the short version of it in Brachah Me'ein Shalosh) was still said; its wording was just different - that Hashem should _preserve_ the city and and the Beis Hamikdash, etc., rather than that He should _rebuild_ them.

Answer (score 1):

It could be referring to fruit trees that are already there, without people planting them. Or, trees planted outside Yerushalayim...